# need to call two branches with in one git repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have a spring client application which is using a cloud server, I have a branch for each environment, for example, client STAG points to STAG branch in http://@giturl.So, what I'm trying to do is creating another branch called common which consists of common properties across the environment. I want to point STAG branch from client application to cloud server and as well as to common branch which retrieves all the common properties used across all the environments, Tried to use the composite type in a cloud server in application.yml by defining the same URL and different labels no luck on that any thoughts?

Tried using the composite type but didn't worked

```
spring:
  profiles: 
    active: composite
  cloud: 
    config: 
      server:
        composite:         
          - 
            type:
            git:
            uri: https://@gitURI
            searchPaths: '{application}/,common/'
          - 
            type:
            git:
            uri: https://@gitURI
            searchPaths: '{application}/'
```

Comment: Why don't you use 1 branch with different profiles? Then you would have `application.properties`, `application-dev.properties`, `application-stag.properties`, `application-prd.properties`, ...

Comment: I have a more than one client application's depend on these branches structure right now. 
So the branches are like,
cloud-config-dev -> {client app's name (sub folder)} -> {application properties}
cloud-config-stag -> {client app's name (sub folder)} -> {application properties}
cloud-config-prod -> {client app's name (sub folder)} -> {application properties}

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you might to look at [this part](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.1.3.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_locating_remote_configuration_resources) of the documentation and play with those 3 properties at the client app, where `label` would be the branch names in a comma separated string. The `searchPaths` property at the server's side would be `{application}` since that is the subfolder.

You might want to consider having multiple config repositories since that will be easier to manage.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: I have read this before if I put them labels as comma separated then first listed string(label)  will be successful and it never goes to the second branch.
For example: 
client app label = cloud-properties-dev, common
So here is the common branch which will consist of all common properties for all environments.
But when the client app runs first it goes to cloud-properties-dev branch get all the properties it found that means it is successfully hit that branch so it never goes to the common branch and never gets the values from them, the client app will fail in this case.

Comment: Then I'd recommend you to go with multiple repositories, each with 1 branch and use the profile specific naming convention for your properties files like I said before.

eg. `spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/myorg/{application}-config`